# SQL server stored procedure timeouts

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

The following stored procedure takes almost 2 minutes to run which is causing a time out.  Both tables do have primary keys and indexes defined.  Is there anyway I can improve the process time?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[dfc_rpt_validation]
 -- declare
    @region varchar(10) = null,
    @source varchar(10) = null
AS BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
select row_number() OVER(ORDER BY l.loan_code) as Id
    , l.region AS Region
    , l.source AS Source
    , l.loan_code_string AS CL_Loan_Code
    , l.loan_principal_amt AS CL_Loan_Principal_Amt
    , l.loan_amt_due AS CL_Loan_Amt_Due
    , l.date_originated AS CL_Origination_Date
    , l.StoreNumber AS CL_Store_Number

    , v.new_loan_code_string  AS FA_Loan_Code
    , v.loan_principal_amt AS FA_Loan_Principal_Amt
    , v.loan_amt_due AS FA_Loan_Amt_Due
    , v.loan_origination_date AS FA_Origination_Date

    , (select count(*) from [dbo].[dfc_LoanValidatedRecords] s WHERE s.loan_code_string = l.loan_code_string) AS FA_Times_Loan_Document_Processed

    , (CASE WHEN l.rejected_date IS NULL AND l.validated_date IS NULL THEN ''
        WHEN v.pdf_legible = 0 THEN 'operational reject' -- operational error
        WHEN v.loan_code_valid = 1
            AND v.loan_principal_amt_valid = 1
            AND v.loan_origination_date_valid = 1
            AND v.loan_amt_due_valid = 1
            --OR v.pdf_legible = 0  -- operational error
        THEN 'validated' ELSE 'rejected' END
        ) AS [FA_Verification_Status]
            -- 100 delivery method failure
            -- 200 pdf reject codes
            -- 400 borrower info reject codes
            -- 600 loan reject codes

            ,  LTRIM(RTRIM (
              --(CASE WHEN l.rejected_date IS NULL AND l.validated_date IS NULL THEN ''
                --ELSE
                (CASE WHEN v.pdf_legible                   = 0 THEN ' 200'
                 ELSE
                 (CASE WHEN v.loan_code_valid             = 0 THEN ' 600' ELSE '' END)
                + (CASE WHEN v.loan_principal_amt_valid    = 0 THEN ' 610' ELSE '' END)
                + (CASE WHEN v.loan_origination_date_valid = 0 THEN ' 620' ELSE '' END) -- LoanDate
                + (CASE WHEN v.loan_amt_due_valid          = 0 THEN ' 625' ELSE '' END)
                END)  -- operational error
              --END)
            )) AS FA_Reason

            , l.load_file AS load_file

from dfc_LoanRecords AS l
JOIN dfc_LoanValidatedRecords AS v ON v.loan_code_string = l.loan_code_string
WHERE CONVERT (DATE, l.load_date) >= convert(date, dateadd(hh,-8,getdate())) -- handle UTC conversion
        AND l.region = @region AND l.source = @source
ORDER BY FA_Verification_Status, FA_Reason
END
```

Comment: Does the query itself take long or query gets slow when run in SP

Comment: Nothing is jumping out as a massive issue here. We would need to see the table definition at the very least. An actual execution plan would be really helpful too.

Comment: Date computing in where predicate, sorting, row_number, subquery... Increase your timeout value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest change I can see:
There's no reason I can see for this: CONVERT (DATE, l.load_date).
Just use l.load_date >= convert(date, dateadd(hh,-8,getdate()))

This should enable SQL query optimiser to use any indexes that might exist on load_date. At the moment it can't do so efficiently as you're using a function on  the column.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't be better if instead of converting the `Convert(date, dateadd(hh,-8,getdate()))`
     in the query itself to avoid that function for every record

```
DECLARE @Date DATE = CAST(DATEADD(HH,-8,GETDATE()) AS DATE)

WHERE CONVERT (DATE, l.load_date) >=  @Date -- handle UTC conversion
    AND l.region = @region AND l.source = @source
```

With this you are going to get a better execution plan instead of converting the value for every single row.

Also if you can apply the `ORDER BY` at the [application layer... please read 7 Things Developers Should Know About SQL Server item 2](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/02/7-things-developers-should-know-about-sql-server/) please do so, there's no need to use it on the database side unless we have to, it will reduce extra-cost on tempdb.

Comment: SQL will parameterise the date constant itself, it's the function on the column you need to be worried about. In fact that might actually make things worse as SQL can't see the value of internal parameters when picking an execution plan for a procedure.

Comment: I perfectly understand that using a function in order to convert values with make things worst but not sure what's the logic he would like to be added for the date range, just to simplify things we can use this 

    l.load_date >=  @Date 

and we are good to go, making a good read from the indexes (if we have an index created for the load_date column )